# How realistic is it to obliterate planet killer with light only?

Tags: internal-consistency, apocalypse, natural-disasters, light

For this purpose you may make the following assumption:

1. No magic, miracle and hope.
2. The asteroid should be on a collision course for us
3. Threat level is omega.
4. Collateral damage must be keep to minimum, acceptable death toll not exceeding 85% of total population at that given time.
5. ETA is 9 years, 9 months, 9 weeks, 9 days, 9 hours, 9 minutes and 9 seconds from now.
6. You must use only light to eliminate the threat which is on course at the speed of 65,000 mph.
7. Using available technology and resources at given time.
8. Only human on Earth are counted.
9. Artificial light only so no solar wind or supernova,etc.

**Can we take out a planet killer with light only?**

Victory condition: at least 15% of human population must be alive and kicking for 48 hours after impact.

Disclaimer: immediate failure to anyone who inquire the distance from impact.

Comment: So how far is it away at the moment? The given speed is just a snapshot and will of course change, but you can't expect me to compute all the different gravitational influences or the final impact speed. ***///*** Jokes aside, I downvote because this question contains some unexplained points in my opinion. What is threat level *omega*? Why only light? How massive is the asteroid? Why only artificial? You impose restrictions and everything which (to me) are essentially random, giving me a hard time taking this both serious and answerable.

Comment: @J_F_B_M: I've already specify ETA and describe it as a planet killer and now asking could we use light to save humanity... I failed to comprehend your doubt I would argued that with a brief window of a decade preparation could we do it or not. OK omega level is just for fun my bad!

Comment: Any particular reason you have "9 months, 9 weeks", instead of "11 months, 1 week", other than you wanted each unit to have the same quantity?

Comment: 65,000 mph is very very close to the earths orbital speed of 67,000 mph

This allows a very wide range of values for what could be considered a planet killer because it takes a far larger rock traveling at 2000 mph relative to the earth (if it's orbiting in the same direction) than one traveling 130,000 mph relative to the earth (if it's orbiting in the opposite direction) to wipe out life. Different again if it's out beyond pluto an dropping towards the sun currently at 65000 mph but speeding up. They also all are different for deflection.

Comment: @Frostfyre: since most of us only have our 10 digits to start with I'll spare you the headaches of borrowing extras...

Comment: @Murphy: not against you but smart ones just give me the proof of concept. (Pun intended)

Comment: Are we assuming a modern day tech level? because I would love to know how we spotted this thing coming from that far out. Also, arbitrary restrictions are arbitrary; if there's a story reason perhaps clue us in? (making up things like "omega" looks unprofessional). Also, I'm pretty sure this is going to be a all-or-nothing survival thing, if it hits at all there are going to be 0 survivors, and if it misses your going to have 100% survivors.

Comment: @user6760 What do you mean planet killer?  Is it an asteroid large enough to wipe out life on the planet (several miles) or large enough to destroy the planet (significantly larger than our moon)

Answer (score 5):

Using lasers to deflect (not destroy) an asteroid is actually one of the best existing ideas for neutralizing a planet-killing threat.  One promising method is called [laser ablation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_Laser_Ablation).  As a laser is trained on a point on an asteroid, the gas and dust that evaporates can create a thrust that will push the rock off-course so that it misses Earth entirely.

Of course, this would take a long time, but a slight change in trajectory can make a big difference over time.  If we had 10 years in advance to prepare, we could probably do it.

Comment: +1 Judging from the numbers given, it's over 5,124,600,000 miles away, which is much further than our favorite asteroid shield: Jupiter.  If the orbital paths line up well enough, we could nudge it into Ol' Jupi.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**
Planet killer asteroid, they have no chance at all - just because of mass. Because to kill a planet, you need something like the moon or bigger and that is a problem.

**YES.**
If you mean a killer asteroid, which will kill the living on the planet, causing mass extinction.
Let say 5-10km in diameter. <strike>Still no.</strike>

ETA 10y means the earth will make ten revolutions around the Sun before impact. That means the average distance will be at least 1 a.e. or more(asteroid orbit inside or close to earth orbit). More likely it will be more, because typical speeds of asteroid bypassing earth are 5-6 km/s (so with 30km/s impact speed it means pretty strange orbit for our system). My guess up 5 a.e. just because of jupiter.

You will be limited not only by atmosphere disturbance but also theoretical limits how small can be focused light spot, at that distances. This shows some possibilities. (it's pretty the same stuff, I hope) [image: Diffraction_limit_diameter_vs_angular_resolution]

Visible light and 100m dish will give you possibility to focus in 0.72 km spot at distance 1 a.u.(atmosphere disturbances is't counted here)

5km asteroid will have mass 64kkk tonne, and if we get some ISP around 100 sec(less is better in that case), then we need to evaporate 64kk tonne to change speed by 1 m/s off the earth direction. It may be enough(needs orbit to say exactly). 1 year with off 1m/s that is ca 30000km miss the target.

So how much energy we need and how much 100m dishes it will be.
So we need at least 3.2e+16 J for propulsion and 1.408e+18 J for evaporation(assume 22MJ/kg, not necessary true, but somewhat realistic).

So if we manage to affect that asteroid for one year period, we need 44 GW power during that year, or with 10% efficiency of our laser setup it will be 440 GW of power. Depending on asteroid composition, it's likely may be gas, not necessary rock, so even 4GW may be enough with gas asteroid.

Average energy density over surface of asteroid(5km radius) will be $\small 293 W/m^2$ - is not much specially if asteroid is mostly rock, but with pulsed mode we still will be able to evaporate rock materials.

Way more better then I assumed in the beginning.

How much dishes we need, with power density 1kW per square meter it's 5,687 dishes and lasers total - one dish per 1.5 million people - not so bad. (actually 2 times more for both sites of earth)

**Yes, it's possible**
For reasonable size asteroid, specially for gaseous one, I have to conclude it's possible, despite my initially thoughts.

Lasers can be of different types, this as example [Carbon dioxide laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_laser), pretty cheap, pretty easy to make, easy to scale production, no need in sophisticated labor.

Tracking target will be some technical challenge, but with our current technology can be done.

Small atmosphere disturbances are not much important, perfect focus is not important, it have to be just enough to hit the asteroid and that's all what is needed, coordination between dishes also not important - they may shoot independently.

So I will upvote question, because it's better inside, then it's looks at first.

Answer (score 1):

The pressure of sunlight on an asteroid can change the orbit over very long periods of time, so in principle light can be used to deflect an asteroid. This isn't going to happen in the time allocated, unless there is action taken to increase the reflectivity or absorption of the sunlight on the asteroid: http://spectrum.ieee.org/aerospace/space-flight/deflecting-asteroids/0

Of course using a laser to ablate part of the asteroid and change its trajectory is using light to deflect an asteroid, but a *lot* of light.

Answer (score 0):

its basically impossible

if you got everyone on planet earth together in one place, and got them all to shine a police searchlight at the moon (lets not worry about how you get everyone here or how you power the lights), you would not see any difference on the moon

that is with about 7.5 BILLION searchlights, now you can ask "what if we add more power", but I don't really see how you can get a lot more power than that